# What is the difference between fluency and thorough knowledge of a language?

Tags: meaning

A job advert states fluency in language A and a thorough knowledge of language B is required. What does thorough knowledge in this context mean? Is it so that my skills in language A need to be better than language B?

Comment: I'd say that thorough knowledge implies knowing grammar and vocabulary but not necessarily being able to speak it fluently or understand complex spoken language immediately, so A would be known better than B. But I don't know if this is in any way standardised.

Comment: There is a Language Learning SE https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Many thanks Stuart for your input!

Comment: The usual distinction is between being an adept speaker and listener on the one hand, and having a thorough reading knowledge.

Comment: Many thanks Tim!

Comment: "thorough knowledge" could also refer to academic study of the language and its structure, having the ability to explain grammar in detail. Fluency refers to being able to use the language easily, like a native speaker.

Comment: The comments above have outlined the distinctions that somebody **could** reasonably try to make by using these terms, but if you are not interested in the matter in general and only want to make sense of this particular job advertisement, then nobody on this site can help you. It's anybody's guess what **they** meant by it; to find out, you have to ask them. Or you can just apply for the job, and let them figure out whether your knowledge of these languages fits what they had in mind.